# How to append data from .load() function to div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if my question confusing, currently i got this working :

```
success: function(json) {
            $('.msgWrapper').load('http://localhost:88/TicketSystem/support/ajaxmsg', {date: json.date, msg: json.msg}).fadeIn("slow");
        }
```

But this only **replace** my div's content with the data returned by the .load() function, i want to **append** the data to my div instead of just replacing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jQuery AJAX shorthand [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method and to get the data, then just append to your element:

```
success: function(json){
    $.post('http://localhost:88/TicketSystem/support/ajaxmsg', { date: json.date, msg: json.msg }, function(data){
        var newData = $('<div>').html(data);
        $('.msgWrapper').append(newData);
        newData.hide().fadeIn("slow");
    };
}
```

Comment: fantastic, since ive got success function inside an ajax post, this one works perfectly. Anyways i never got .fadeIn() to work, any suggestion?

Comment: Are you after `.msgWrapper` to fade in, or are you trying to fade in an element within the `.msgWrapper` that was just appended?

Comment: i just wanna fade the data that was just appended.

Comment: I've updated my answer to wrap the appended content in a `<div>` which is then faded in.

Comment: just perfect, thanks alot Scrooby, sorry i dont have enough reputation to vote this up.

Answer (score 3):

```
var $temp = $('<div>').load('http://localhost:88/TicketSystem/support/ajaxmsg', {date: json.date, msg: json.msg});
$('.msgWrapper').append($temp.html()).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just send the POST request and append manually:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:88/TicketSystem/support/ajaxmsg',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        date: json.date,
        msg: json.msg
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('.msgWrapper').append(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".msgWrapper").append($("<div>").load('http://localhost:88/TicketSystem/support/ajaxmsg', {date: json.date, msg: json.msg}).fadeIn("slow");
```